# Is it possible in a multiindexed Pandas dataframe to have a column whose values refer to a higher level index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose I have such a dataframe in Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,4,8,8],'b':[4,5,6,5], 'd':[0,1,2,1]})
multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]])
df.index= multi_idx
```

which outputs this shape:

```
     a  b  d
0 0  4  4  0
  1  4  5  1
1 0  8  6  2
  1  8  5  1
```

You see that values of columns `a` are repeated based on the first level index. I am looking for a way to avoid this repetition. One of course would be to split the information across more dataframes, i.e., having a data frame for column `a` and first level index. However, I was wondering if there is somehow a way using multiindex and multi level columns, to create a columns whose values correspond to all rows of a higher level index.

Visually I would like something like that: is that possible in Pandas?

```
|    |    |  a  |  b  |  c  | 
|----|----|-----|-----|-----|
|idx1|idx2|     |     |     |
|----|----|-----|-----|-----|
|    |  0 |     |  4  |  0  |
|  0 |----|  4  |-----|-----|
|    |  1 |     |  5  |  1  |
|----|----|-----|-----|-----|
|    |  0 |     |  6  |  2  |
|  1 |----|  8  |-----|-----|
|    |  1 |     |  5  |  1  |
|----|----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Comment: No, it's not possible, there are no merged cells in pandas.

Comment: @mozway, This is an answer for me, if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, I also added a workaround using post-processing of the dataframe's HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible, pandas doesn't have a concept of merged cells.

If you want to "merge" contiguous identical cells, you either have to use a MultiIndex to benefit from this display (only on the initial levels though) or to post-process the html output to change the rowspan of those cells manually.

Example to process the HTML, partially with pandas to compute the size of the rowspan and with `BeautifulSoup` to modify the HTML:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from IPython.display import display
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def to_rowspan(s):
    m = s.ne(s.groupby(level=0).shift())
    sz = s.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('size')
    return [f'[rowspan={size}]{val}' if mask else 'TO_DELETE'
            for size, mask, val in zip(sz, m, s)]

def merge_cells(df):
    reg = re.compile(r'\[rowspan=(\d+)\](.*)')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(df.apply(to_rowspan).to_html())
    
    for row in soup.find_all('td'):
        if row.text == 'TO_DELETE':
            row.decompose()
        elif (m:=reg.search(row.text)):
            a,b = m.groups() ; a = int(a)
            if a>1:
                row['rowspan'] = a
            row.string = b
    return soup.prettify()

display(HTML(merge_cells(df)))
```

Output:

[image]